# MacBook Pro keyboard and trackpad not working

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, macbook

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro 13" without touchbar (2 usb-c ports)
I am trying to install ubuntu from a usb to another usb, but my keyboard and trackpad is not working on the installation, or live ubuntu.
I tried connecting a wireless mouse with a usb input, and it works. But then I am left with only 1 usb port available.
Is there a way to use my MacBook's keyboard and trackpad instead? Because even if a buy like a usb-c to 3 usb-a adapter, I don't really want to use external keyboard and mouse all the time.
Thank you..

Answer (score 4):

The newest line of MacBook Pros is poorly supported by Ubuntu (and vice versa). While it is possible to get Ubuntu working, it will take some extra work until Ubuntu catches up with the hardware changes.

To get your builtin trackpad and keyboard working, use a USB keyboard and mouse for the installation (you'll likely run into NVMe SSD issues that you can learn more about [here](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux#nvme) when selecting your partition setup)

When your install is complete, refer to [this link](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux#keyboard--touchpad) to regain control of your builtin hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue using a Virtual Machine (parallels) and instead of loading Linux 4, I selected the previous Linux 4 and it worked so logically it could be something in Linux 5's kernal that is not supporting the trackpad/mouse driver for the Macbook Pro.