# Ubuntu on Macbook Pro trackpad not smooth

Tags: touchpad, macbook

This probably has been answered somewhere but I didn't find the exactly solution. Most seem to point to how to get mac gesture working.

I installed Ubuntu on my late 2015 Macbook Pro 13in. After I find the trackpad is just a little off. It seems it becomes less sensitive. Sometime it wouldnt detect,it ends up almost 1cm movement without response. So the movement of the cursor is not smooth sometime. This can be frustrating as I can even struggle to navigate to a specific location I want.

Any solution to this. Ps. I am new to Linux but has basic unix experience from Mac.

Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the exact Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Yes my bad, I added. It is Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0):

No accepted answer on the following post, and it seems to be mostly speculative, however referring to a similar, but-not-same [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962022/macbook-pro-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working), there is a Github repository with driver patches for your model of MacBook. The full github page can be found [here](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux#keyboard--touchpad), but for you specifically;

> For models with a T2 chip (MacBookPro15,* MacBookPro16,1) you'll need
>   the BCE drivers from https://github.com/MCMrARM/mbp2018-bridge-drv and
>   the touchpad and keyboard patches from
>   https://github.com/aunali1/linux-mbp-arch

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not correct. OP's model is too old to have a T2 chip, and given that the trackpad works *at all* means the BCE drivers are not necessary. On T2 models and newer, the out-of-tree patches you linked are 100% required for the internal keyboard & trackpad to even be recognized by the kernel.